# Laravel (5.4) throws 404 on valid API route

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404

I've been trying to solve this using various different suggestions but nothing seems to work, and although it's possible I'm missing something really obvious, I just don't understand why I'm getting a 404 error on a route that definitely exists.

I have a CRM that amongst other options allows the user to delete a 'deliverable' (a file attached to a case) but for some reason I always get a 404 when trying to execute it.

Here's the call in the React component:

```
documentCollectionRepo.removeDeliverable(deliverable.id).then(showSuccess, showError);
```

`deliverable.id` definitely exists, as I have console logged it out.

Here is the function in the repo:

```
export function removeDeliverable(documentCollectionId) {
   return Api.remove(`document-collections/${documentCollectionId}`);
}
```

And finally, here is the route in the API routes file:

```
Route::delete('document-collections/{documentCollectionId}', 'DocumentCollectionController@deleteDocumentCollection');
```

When I click the Delete button to run the relevant function, the Network tab shows the following error (IP hidden in this quote):

> Request URL: http://192.168.50.52/api/v1/document-collections/3
>   Request Method: DELETE 
> Status Code: 404 Not Found 
> Remote Address:
>   192.168.xx.xx:80 
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

The `deleteDocumentCollection()` function definitely exists in the `DocumentCollectionController.php` file and every other function works (including another delete route) - so I don't quite understand why this route wouldn't work. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the controller function:

```
public function deleteDocumentCollection(DeleteDocumentCollectionRequest $req, $documentCollectionId)
{
    $this->documentCollectionRepository->delete($documentCollectionId);

    return response()->ok();
}
```

And in the repo:

```
public function delete($fileId)
{
    $file = $this->getOne($fileId);

    $this->deleteUploadedFile($file);
    $this->deleteNotifications($file);
    $this->deleteNotes($file);

    $file->delete();
}
```

Comment: Could you also post the group(s) by which this route is surrounded? And does your laravel log contain any errors?

Comment: All the routes are wrapped in `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'store-last-active']], function() {` group and no, there are no additional errors in the log, just the 404

Answer (score 0):

If you Laravel Project is configured on Apache, then it might occur such issue.

Because Apache doesn't allow DELETE requests, so the response will be 404.

Add this to .htaccess after the Laravel default codes:

```
<Limit DELETE>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

Again this can be the possible case. and if it still don't work, please share your code in brief so i can look into it.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually I use nginx, and also as I stated in my question all other delete requests work fine - it's literally just that one

Comment: Can you please only share code of `deleteDocumentCollection()` function ?

Comment: I have added them to the question